# Gvistable assign color to each row/cell

Tags: r, google-visualization, shiny, ggvis

I have a shiny-app with gvistables. I need to change either the font color or the background color of each row in my tables. The closest I got is to change the background color of the entire table. Is it possible to change back ground or the text color of each row?!
I have presented a code with sample data using population data.

```
require(shiny)
require(googleVis)
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("googleVis on Shiny"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("table")
      ,tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", ".myTableHeadrow {background-color:red;} .myTablerow {background-color:yellow;}"))
    )
  ),
  server =function(input, output)({
    output$table <- renderGvis({
      ## Table with enabled paging
      tbl2 <- gvisTable(Population[1:5, ], options=list(page='enable', height=300, cssClassNames = "{headerRow: 'myTableHeadrow', tableRow: 'myTablerow'}", alternatingRowStyle = FALSE), chartid = "mytable")
      tbl2
    })    
  })
  )
)
```

My HTML understanding is not good enough to figure this out. Any help is appreciated!

I came across the following piece of JSCode which colors the background and the text as I need.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
data.addRows([
  ['Shoes', 10700],
  ['Sports', -15400],
  ['Toys', 12500],
  ['Electronics', -2100],
  ['Food', 22600],
  ['Art', 1100]
]);

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('colorformat_div'));

var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
formatter.addRange(-20000, 0, 'white', 'orange');
formatter.addRange(20000, null, 'red', '#33ff33');
formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
```

Can someone please help me in figuring how to adapt it to shiny??